# Jest test breaks on ngx-bootstrap BsModalService

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngx-bootstrap

I am switching to Jest for unit testing and have an angular 6 project using ngx-bootstrap. I get the error down below when running npm test.

I have a project to demonstrate this issue here: https://github.com/ronlawrence3/ngx-bootstrap-example (jasmine branch works, master jest test does not).

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Error:

```
$ npm test

> ngx-bootstrap-example@0.0.0 test /home/ron/p/ngx-bootstrap-example-jasmine
> jest

 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  AppComponent
    ✕ should create the app (428ms)
    ✕ should have as title 'app' (9ms)

  ● AppComponent › should create the app

    Can't resolve all parameters for BsModalService: (?, ?).

      at syntaxError (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:959:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:839:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:1091:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:1102:16)
      at ../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:1023:38
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:983:15)
      at ../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:532:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.Object.<anonymous>.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:524:43)
      at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:127:49)
      at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.Object.<anonymous>.JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:69:33)
      at CompilerImpl.Object.<anonymous>.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../execroot/angular/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:68:27)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.Object.<anonymous>.TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../execroot/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:57:27)
      at TestBed.Object.<anonymous>.TestBed.compileComponents (../../../../execroot/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:335:27)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.TestBed.compileComponents (../../../../execroot/packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:116:66)
      at src/app/app.component.spec.ts:16:9
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
      at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:106:39)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:125:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.runGuarded (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47)
      at runInTestZone (node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:234:29)
      at node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:168:17
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:43)
      at Object.testBody.length.done (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:51:29)
```

Comment: jest uses umd bundles to run test but ngx-bootstrap shipped wrong version. Here is your issue https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4380

Comment: Thanks, @yurzui. I'll follow that issue.